# whether it takes long time for convert flv to MP4 using ffmpeg from server

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I want to convert a flv file to mp4. I use with a basic command like this :

```
ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/rawmedia/d2cb9f152f27d9beb4a15d61e177fa22.flv /var/www/html/media/new.mp4
```

The command above has result 0 B mp4. 
I read for My reference for this in this [link](http://www.mmtek.com/dp20090929/node/69), 
there is a very simple and basic I think. 
So I try the command above for testing php vibe command like this :

```
ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/rawmedia/d2cb9f152f27d9beb4a15d61e177fa22.flv -vcodec libx264 -s 640x360 -threads 4 -movflags faststart /var/www/html/media/test4.mp4
```

I got that command from PHPVIBE for convert other format file except mp4.
So I got a result just the same as like first command that still 0 B mp4.
But the Output of the second command give me like this

```
Incompatible sample format 's16' for codec 'aac', auto-selecting format 'flt'
[libx264 @ 0xcebde0] using cpu capabilities: none!
[libx264 @ 0xcebde0] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0xcebde0] 264 - core 120 r2151 a3f4407 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=4 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[NULL @ 0xd5f1a0] Codec is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, see -strict -2
Output #0, mp4, to '/var/www/html/media/test4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    starttime       : 0
    totalduration   : 57
    totaldatarate   : 353
    bytelength      : 2535814
    canseekontime   : true
    sourcedata      : B0AFCE7F5HH1428394559963956
    purl            :
    pmsg            :
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 640x360, q=-1--1, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: none, 22050 Hz, stereo, flt, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (flv -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp3 -> aac)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Output give me some information that test.mp4 have  `bytelength      : 2535814`.
But I still have  0B mp4 converted result until now. Is there taking a time or I was wrong with the command. But especially my first command very basic and still get zero byte result.

Comment: Perhaps that error message `Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit__rate, rate, width or height` should give you a clue

Comment: I've try to adjust according with rate. Example : 

ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/rawmedia/d2cb9f152f27d9beb4a15d61e177fa22.flv -b:v 287k -ab 64k /var/www/html/media/testagain3.mp4 . I still that errors .

Comment: You trimmed the console output and omitted the configure and version info which is often useful and always informative.